# Both `symfony new --full` and `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton testweb` doesn't create project

Tags: symfony, symfony4

After not doing anything in Symfony for a year, today I tried to create a Symfony 4 project for a small landing. The problem is both `symfony new --full testweb` and `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton testweb` returned a success but didn't created all the project files.

### Creating project by composer:

```
J:\_online\aaaform.testy.ovh>composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton testweb
Installing symfony/website-skeleton (v4.3.99)
  - Installing symfony/website-skeleton (v4.3.99): Loading from cache
Created project in testweb
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.3.*"
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/flex (v1.4.6): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Symfony operations: 1 recipe (16fe55e9bbdda89a25a3cc57ebd8163c)
  - Configuring symfony/flex (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master

Some files may have been created or updated to configure your new packages.
Please review, edit and commit them: these files are yours.
```

### Creating project by symfony new:

```
J:\_online\aaaform.testy.ovh>symfony new --full testweb
 * Creating a new Symfony project with Composer
  (running C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.bat create-project symfony/website-skeleton testweb)

* Setting up the project under Git version control
  (running git init testweb)


 [OK] Your project is now ready in J:\_online\aaaform.testy.ovh\testweb
```

### The directory structure created by the commands:

```
.git
vendor
.env
composer.json
composer.lock
symfony.lock
```

I cleared the composer cache by `composer clearcache` successfully few times but still nothing changes. Its like flex failes to use the recipe. I'm using php 7.3.11 and the version returned both by console and `composer -vvv about` is same.

### Composer diagnose output:

```
composer diagnose
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 1.9.1
PHP version: 7.3.11
PHP binary path: C:\php\php.exe
```

So what am I missing? Why Symfony project isn't created?

Comment: I just tried symfony new --full and it all worked as expected.

Comment: I use  `create-project` at least weekly, and it works as intended. There is something wrong in your end.

Comment: It looks like the recipes were not executed. Maybe you lost internet connection and the vendor files were installed from cache? In any case you should be able to get the full directory structure by running `composer sync-recipes` inside your project.

Comment: @Cerad, I know the commands work, but they don't work for me.

Comment: @yivi I know there is something at my end, but nothing returns errors.

Comment: @dbrumann I did use the sync-recipies, execution succeed but still nothing changes.

Comment: Can you run the command with `-vvv` and add the output to the question?

Comment: Can  you use the Linux subsystem? Or try it in a different machine? It may be something related to PHP/Composer/Windows juxtaposition, but it's very hard if not impossible for someone other than you to debug.

Comment: @yivi I did used Debian on VPS to generate structure and downloaded full system into my IDE. But that's just a work around. And I know its hard, especially when composer doesn't return errors. The only strange thing I found while creating project with -vvv option is that line: `Failed to initialize global composer: The "remove-vcs" option does not exist.` But composer basicaly ignores it and goes forward. Funny thing is that this option exists in composer documentation of 1.9.1 and it is the version I use.

Comment: What version of windows are you using? Don't you have the WSL available?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, and no, I don't have WSL. This is the system I was using already for creating Symfony projects. And It wasn't reinstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was corrupt `Composer` installation. It was updated to 1.9.1 using `composer self-update` successfully but apparently failed. Uninstallation of Composer and removing the `Composer` directory from `AppData` following with new Composer installation worked perfectly.